# How to show hint only in Header in TVirtualStringtree?

Tags: delphi

I want to show Hint only when user moves mouse over Header in TVirtualStringTree, not over Data nodes. Right now I can only show it Data nodes and not in Header, with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns.Add.Text := 'Brand';
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[0].Width := 100;
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns.Add.Text := 'Model';
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[1].Width := 100;

  // Set the Hint text
  VirtualStringTree1.Hint := 'Click to sort by Car brand';

  // Show Header
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options := VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options + [hoVisible];

  // Enable Hint in Header
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options := VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options + [hoShowHint];

  // Disable the Hint in Data nodes
  VirtualStringTree1.ShowHint := False;
end;
```

With this code there is no hint displayed anywhere, not in Data nodes and not in Header.

If I set:

```
// Enable Hint in Data nodes
VirtualStringTree1.ShowHint := True;
```

In this case the Hint is shown in Data nodes, but not in Header even if `[hoShowHint]` is added to Header.Options.

How can I show hint only in  Header and not in Data nodes - so user can see 'Click to sort by Car brand' only when mouse is over Header and not over Data nodes?

Comment: Doesn't each column has a Hint property?

Comment: Now I know it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show hints in `TVirtualStringTree` (in the following `VST`) column headers:

1. With column editor open, select a column in the editor.
2. In Object Inspector locate the `Hint` property and enter text
3. With the `VST` selected look for property `Header - Options - hoShowHint` and set to true.
4. With the `VST` selected look for property `ShowHint` and set to true.
5. To show a hint in the "data" area, enter the hint text in the `Hint` property. To not show a hint in the "data" area, clear the `Hint` property.

In your code you are missing the lines where you enter the text for the column header hints:

```
  VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[0].Hint := 'Hint for first column header';
```

and similar for the other columns.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need, so I can set hint for each column. Looking through examples I couldn't find this.